# Python - error: [Errno 111] Connection refused and error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, sockets

I'm in the process of learning how to use threads and socket connections.
I've found literature and examples online on how threads and socket connections work.  Now I'm trying to merge the two together to create a simple send/receive application.  So here is what I put together as an example:

main.py,

```
import server
import client
import threading

def main():
    try:
        threadA = threading.Thread(target=server.serv)
        threadA.start()

        threadB = threading.Thread(target=client.client)
        threadB.start()
    except:
        print "Got an Error"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> server.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is server.py file

import socket               # Import socket module

def serv():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12920                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port

s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
#while True:
c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
print 'Got connection from', addr
c.send('Thank you for connecting')
s.shutdown(1)
c.close()                # Close the connection
```

> client.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is client.py file

import socket               # Import socket module

def client():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)         # Create a socket object
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
    port = 12920                # Reserve a port for your service.

    s.connect((host, port))
    print s.recv(1024)
    s.shutdown(1)
    s.close                     # Close the socket when done
```

I able to run the application for the first time without any errors.  Here is the output:
Got connection from ('172.17.132.98', 50759)
Thank you for connecting

When I run the application again (for the second time consecutive), I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                 
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 813, in __bootstrap_inner                                                                                         
       self.run()                                                                                                                                                     
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 766, in run                                                                                                       
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)                                                                                                                   
File "/home/cg/root/client.py", line 12, in client                                                                                                               
    s.connect((host, port))                                                                                                                                        
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth                                                                                                         
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)                                                                                                                         
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Here I hit the ctrl+Z key to halt the hung application.

And if I try to run the application again, I receive the following error:
Exception in thread Thread-1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                 
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 813, in __bootstrap_inner                                                                                         
    self.run()                                                                                                                                                     
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 766, in run                                                                                                       
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)                                                                                                                   
  File "/home/cg/root/server.py", line 11, in serv                                                                                                                 
    s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port                                                                                                                 
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth                                                                                                         
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)                                                                                                                         
error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks InAdvance

Comment: ctrl+Z suspends the process in the background and so the socket my still be bound, hence the "Address is already in use"

Comment: But why does it hang with after running the app the first time with the following error:  error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
I would expect to run this back to back without encountering any issues.

Comment: You should catch a KeyBoardInterrupt and kill the server

Answer (score 2):

Your client code does not actually close the connection.  Your code has the following:

```
s.close
```

which should be:

```
s.close()
```

As such, you are leaving the connection open on the server and the resource is not getting freed properly.  This is why you are getting the Address In use error.  The port is still bound and "in use".

In addition, if you use "Ctrl+Z" to suspend the application, it is still executing in the background and the resources have not been freed.  You would need to actually terminate the process to free the resources.

Comment: after the socket closes, is there a period wait time to wait before a new socket can be created to use the same port and transmit data?  I find that rerunning the same application causes non-repeatable results.  Sometime it works, sometimes it fails.

Answer (score 0):

> Here I hit the ctrl+Z key to halt the hung application.

There's your problem. To stop an application you have to hit ctrl+c; with ctrl+z you just send it to the background. The application is still open and using that same address and port.

If you send an application to the background, you can bring it back with `fg`, keep it running in the background with `bg` or kill it with `kill %1`. Killing it (or bringing it back to the foreground and stopping it with ctrl+c) should release the resource.

Answer (score 0):

I found out for my example, there was a timing issue between the starting threadA and threadB.  A race condition between the server and client.  So I added a threading._sleep(1) between them and did not encounter the bogus errors I was encountering previously.

Thank You all for helping me.  I gained a bit more in understanding how threads and sockets work together.